# Есть ли разница в названии переменной в Windows? Path или PATH

Tags: windows-7

Когда я впервые начал добавлять пути в переменных заметил, что название переменных среды текущего пользователя было `PATH`, а системных `Path`. Стоит ли мне их переименовать в `Path`, или в `PATH`? А то в гугле все пишут то ли `PATH`, то ли `Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызовы в системе Windows изначально не зависят от регистра, поэтому неважно как вы назовете свою переменную: `Path`, `PATH`, `path`, `pATh` и т.д. Главное придерживайтесь одного стиля и не создавайте переменные с одинаковым именем в окне работы с ними (`Path` + `pAtH` - одна перекроет другую).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вопрос появился. А системная переменная не перекрывает переменные текущего пользователя? (PATH(пользователя) + Path(системное))

Comment: @user425799, нет, приоритет выше у переменной пользователя. Можно проверить, заведя переменные в системе и потом выполнив команду в CMD `echo %PATH%` или любую другую `echo %Имя%`.

Comment: Спасибо. Не нашел в гугле про переменные, а именно про нейминг. Еще раз спасибо.